# Powershell, getting substring using regular expression and special characters

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I have to extract the user info from this line

```
"user/data ^`ms\john ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
```

The pattern is that the info always comes between `"user/data ^`" and `"^`"

The expected result is "ms\john"

This is my attempt,

```
$line = "user/data ^`ms\john ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
if ($line -match "user/data(.*)")
{
    write-host "found: $($matches[1])"
} else {
    Write-Host "no found"
}
```

I don't know how to add special characters in the regexp and extract "ms\john".

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more options:

```
PS> $il = "user/data ^`ms\john ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem"

PS> $il -replace '^user/data\ \^`([^\^]+)\ \^.+$','$1'
ms\john

PS> [regex]::Matches($il,'user/data\s\^`([^\^]+)\s\^').Groups[1].Value
ms\john
```

Comment: it works fine but if I try to read the same line from a text file I get "`ms\john". Notice the rave accent or backtick. +1

Comment: it worked, thanks Shay.Can you please explain why the previous one did not work.

Comment: PowerShell expands the backtick inside double quotes. You can see the difference if you execute these too: "`^" and '`^'

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this:

```
$line = "user/data ^`ms\john ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
if ($line -match "user/data\s+\^`?([^\^]+)")
{
    write-host "found: $($matches[1])"
} else {
    Write-Host "no found"
}
```

Comment: +1, the regexp works fine but if I try to read the line from a text line then a backtick is added, any clues? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$line = "user/data ^`ms\john ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem ^`Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
if ($line -match "(?<=\^)(.[^\^]*)")
{
    write-host "found: $($matches[1])"
} else {
    Write-Host "no found"
}
```

Comment: +1, Thanks Christian. The regular expression works fine as I stated however if I try to read the same line from a text file, a rave accent is added at the beginning of the captured string like if the text file is being added an additional character.